# Define get/set in constructor function

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

This can be done:

```
var o = {
  _foo : "bar",
  get Foo() { return _foo; },
  set Foo(value) { _foo = value; }
};
```

But my code is defined in a constructor function, so I want something like this:

```
function Something(defaultFoo) {
  var _foo = defaultFoo;
  get Foo() { return _foo; };               // invalid syntax
  set Foo(value) { _foo = value; };         // invalid syntax
}

var something = new Something("bar");
console.log(something.Foo);
```

That syntax is invalid. Is there some variation that works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the prototype property and assign the setter and getter.

BTW, you need to use `_foo` as property, not as local variable.

```js
function Something(defaultFoo) {
    this._foo = defaultFoo;
}

Object.defineProperty(Something.prototype, 'foo', {
    get: function() {
        return this._foo;
    },
    set: function(value) {
        this._foo = value;
    }
});

var something = new Something("bar");
console.log(something.foo);
something.foo = 'baz';
console.log(something.foo);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could combine both ideas with `Object.defineProperty`:

```
function Something(defaultFoo) {
    var _foo = defaultFoo;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "Foo", {
        get: function() { return _foo },
        set: function(value) { _foo = value }
    });
}
```

Make sure however to reference `_foo` consistently like that, not as `this._foo`, since you never defined that.

Alternatively, with ES6 class notation (together with private fields added since ES2020), you can do this -- and here I stored the value in the private `#foo` field:

```
class Something {
    #foo
    constructor(defaultFoo) {
        this.#foo = defaultFoo;
    }
    get Foo() { return this.#foo; }
    set Foo(value) { this.#foo = value; }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  In prototypal inheritance, setters/getters belong as privileged methods, not public, because the latter cannot access private variables.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe, I took the opportunity to upgrade the class version of the code to include a private field; a feature introduced by ES2020.

Comment: One small thing... in my testing for the prototypal version: the setters/getters were not called when using `Object.assign(this, {...})`.  Using `Object.defineProperty(this, 'Foo', {...})` did work.